# How to made a redirection if overflow on pagy array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

I have an index view with 45 products and 3 pages.

I'm using pagy_array like :
`@pagy, @products = pagy_array(products, items: 20)`

If I delete 6 products, I get 39 items on 2 pages. But Google have indexed the third page, and when a customer come on this page, he get an error `expected :page in 1..2; got 3`

How can I compare the params[:page] to the @pagy.page and made a redirect 301 if bigger ?

Answer (score 4):

Please check this documentation. You can configure this in the pagy.rb initialiser

https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras/overflow

```
in the pagy.rb initializer:

require 'pagy/extras/overflow'

# default :empty_page (other options :last_page and :exception )
Pagy::VARS[:overflow] = :last_page

# OR
require 'pagy/countless'
require 'pagy/extras/overflow'

# default :empty_page (other option :exception )
Pagy::VARS[:overflow] = :exception
```

Other options for handling overflow - `:last_page, :empty_page or :exception`

Comment: I have added initializer with overflow condition but it's not working. It still throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

to fix it on current date 08/31/2023

in the pagy.rb initializer

> #to return last available page

```
require "pagy/extras/overflow"

Pagy::DEFAULT[:overflow] = :last_page
```

> #to return empty page

```
require "pagy/extras/overflow"

Pagy::DEFAULT[:overflow] = :empty_page
```